# jQuery Mask not allowing recursive input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to mask a form field to only allow facebook page urls, using jQuery Mask Plugin (http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).  The current code I'm using is this:

```
$('input.facebook').mask('https://facebook.com/R', {translation:  {'R': {pattern: /[\S]/},recursive: true}, maxlength: false});
```

This almost works, but I can only enter a single character after the '...k.com/', when I need to be able to enter any number of characters.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: thank you asked for it, the documentation of jquery igor is absolutely crap, i searched 3 hours for such simple masking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the recursive option is in the incorrect place, it should be a sibling of the pattern.

http://jsfiddle.net/WXnh8/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.facebook').mask('https://facebook.com/ZZ', {
    translation: {
      'Z': { pattern: /\S/, optional: true, recursive: true}
    },
    maxlength: false
  });
});
```

*We use ZZ instead of just Z in the matcher because recursive is meant to repeat any static characters intrinsic to the mask, so for some reason, if there's only one matching character, it repeats the static character before it.*

Comment: the whole purpose of the recursive option is to not have to do something messy like this.  I just need the correct syntax for it to actually work.  some of the demos use the recursive option.  You can see them here: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I've narrowed down the problem, the recursive option should be a sibling parameter to the pattern. (Updated original post w/ code and new fiddle.) However, jQuery Mask seems to be adding slash characters to the input unwantedly when the recursive matcher immediately follows a slash.

Comment: A post on the author's blog indicates that having prefixes/suffixes in the mask isn't really supported inherently by this plugin, so the code I edited above is the correct usage of the recursive functionality, however what you're trying to accomplish might not be natively possible in this case. http://www.igorescobar.com/blog/2012/05/06/masks-with-jquery-mask-plugin/comment-page-2/#comment-75846

Comment: Your version actually works well, if you make Z optional, and then make the mask `'https://facebook.com/ZZ'`.  recursive is meant to repeat any static characters intrinsic to the mask, so for some reason, if there's only one matching character, it repeats the static character before it.  I'm going to accept your answer, but it could use the necessary edit.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the documentation of jquery igor is absolutely crap, i searched 3 hours for such simple masking